# Infinite rebuild loop in Laravel mix watch mode

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, webpack, infinite-loop, laravel-mix

Using PhpStorm 2020.1 under Xubuntu 18.04, I'm building a JS game into a Laravel 6.18.8 fresh install.

Each time I run `npm run watch` or `npm run watch-poll`, my assets keep being rebuilded infinitely.

Here is my config:

```js
// Dependencies in package.json:
"devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "cross-env": "^7.0",
    "fibers": "^4.0.2",
    "jquery": "^3.5.0",
    "laravel-mix": "^5.0.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.13",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "pixi.js": "^5.2.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.0",
    "sass": "^1.15.2",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  }

// webpack.mix.js config:
mix
    .copyDirectory('resources/images', 'public/images')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .extract(['lodash', 'popper.js', 'jquery', 'bootstrap', 'axios', 'pixi.js'])
    .version(['public/images'])
    .sourceMaps()
;
```

I googled a lot, and mainly find [this solution](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/228), but changing `processCssUrls` option doesn't change anything.
**Please note that none of my app images are used from any scss files, so I don't think it's a rewrite url issue.**

Digging deeper, I used following plugin too see which file triggers the rebuild:

```js
class WatchRunPlugin {
    apply(compiler) {
        compiler.hooks.watchRun.tap('WatchRun', (comp) => {
            let mtimes = comp.watchFileSystem.watcher.mtimes;
            let changes = Object.keys(mtimes);
            if (changes.length) {
                changes = changes.map(file => `  ${file} (${mtimes[file]})\n`).join('');
                console.log(`CHANGES:\n${changes}`);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

On each rebuild, it only shows `/public/mix-manifest.json` with a new timestamp as if this file update triggers a rebuild.
I tried to ignore it, but this doesn't change anything too;

```js
mix
    .webpackConfig({
        watchOptions: {
            ignored: ['public/mix-manifest.json']
        }
    })
    // ...
    ;
```

Finally, I try to remove every statment from `webpack.mix.js` one by one, but the issue still happens no matter the rebuild tasks defined.
Could this issue being caused by OS and/or IDE ?

It's driving me crazy, and I'm running out of options here ^^
Any help would be really appreciated, thanks in advance.

---

**EDIT**

I was importing `/public/mix-manifest.json` into my script (thought it was smart to use it as assets manifest for my game).
So each time the manifest was created, a rebuild was triggered, and then manifest was created again, then ... infinite loop!

Changed that to a proper & dedicated method to manage game assets manifest and everything's fine now.
Stupid, but took me out some time to figure it out ...

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't figured it out yet. Try disabling the "auto-save" for PhpStorm. Every time you write something in the IDE it automatically saves it which causes the assets to re-compile again and again.

```
Open PhpStorm settings (Command + , on Mac) > 
Appearance & Behaviour > 
System Settings > 
uncheck "Save files on frame deactivation" and "Save files automatically if application is idle for ..."
```